# Revert to the page's original CSS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page with a 'printer friendly' button that uses jQuery's .css() method to remove some backgrounds and border from specific elements, and change the font size. I can set another .css() method to change everything back to the way it was, but is there any easy way to revert everything on the page to its original CSS (aside from refreshing the page)?

Comment: Why all the fiddly JavaScript? Just use a print media stylesheet from the get go. Then it will "Just Work" when the user prints. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: Had no idea this existed. Thank you.

Comment: I realize the answer it the "right" way but I'd still like to know how to do what you actually asked via jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define your print friendly styles as selector rules in your main css file

```
body.printfriendly .selector .rule
{
  font-size:bigger;
}
```

And then you can add and remove the `printfriendly` class on the body tag to show or hide the rules.

You can also use the `@media print` section to declare rules that only get applied when the user prints.

```
@media print 
{
   .selector .rule
   {
     font-size:bigger;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can remove all inline styles by doing something like

```
$('*[style]').removeAttr('style');
```

It will remove all styles set by jQuery, but also potentially any other inline styles set in the HTML. Not that I recommend it though.

I understand that you might not want to use a print style sheet. Some users would like to print the page as they see it, and you might want to add a preview before actually printing.

I recommend using a `.printfriendly` class that you can toggle to the `body` tag. That way you have full control in the CSS, and presentation layer.

Comment: Although I agree with other answers and comments for the OP's specific usage, this answer actually answers the question in the title and was therefore what I was looking for. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use .removeClass to remove the class you attached

```
.addClass('printFriendly');

.removeClass('printFriendly');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a print style sheet that builds on top of you screen stylesheet?
This would be much cleaner:

in your HTML template:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in your print.css:

```
@import "screen.css";
// overwrite disired parts of your screen.css
```

Now you can add a button with the following javascript command:

```
document.print();
```

to open the browsers default print promt.

Answer (score 0):

The printer friendly button is pretty old school.  CSS 2 has a [media rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) mechanism.

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
}
```